# Problems with a JQuery Function to Extract Links from Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, hyperlink

I've written a JQuery function to extract the link data stored within object tags on a webpage. I want to create a direct link to the item being embed with the object tag. This is the function:

```
function() {
  var allObjects = document.querySelectorAll('object');

  // Iterate through objects
  $('object').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is('[name="nameMarker"]')) {
      //the object has already been changed
    } else {  
      //the link needs to be generated
      $(this).attr('name', 'nameMarker')
      var href = $(this).attr('data');
      $(this).append('<a href="' + href '">link</a>');
    }
  });
}
```

The problem is that the function only results in a question mark appearing after the document embed in the object tag. Does any one know why the function isn't working?

Here is an example of what the object tag will look like before extracting the link:

```
    <object data="documentURL.pdf" type="application/pdf" internalinstanceid="68">
<a href="documentURL.pdf">
[Embedded PDF: documentURL.pdf ]</a></object>
```

Comment: can you add some html to show what the object looks like? function looks fine on its own

Comment: even better if you can set up a snippet or a jsfiddle

Comment: You are missing a `+` after `href` when you generate the links.

Comment: I tried adding a + directly after each href, I still only get a question mark.

Comment: I just tried your code by adding the missing "+" sign and it works. Check it out http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/OMwdMJ?editors=1010

Comment: Even when directly copying and pasting your code into my test environment, all I get is the question mark

Comment: I saw the same thing as @zeropoint when I updated the link line to br `$(this).append('<a href="'+href+'">link</a>');`. Could you post an example of the HTML output, with the question mark in the link?